# How to set two Events in One Button Click?

Tags: c#, forms, events, timer

I have Form with a Timer1.

I would like to set the Tick event of that timer1 to a `timer2_Tick` function that is already signed to another timer2.

How can I Set the 2 timers, to 1 event?

Comment: Have you tried it?  You can assign the same event handelr to two objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do it the same way you assign any other event handler, you just happen to choose the same method for both timers.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer first = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
first.Tick += tick;

System.Windows.Forms.Timer second = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
second.Tick += tick;

private void tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

If you're using the designer, instead of attaching the events through code, then you can just go to the "Properties" tab, select events, and enter the same name for the `Tick` event for both timers.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign same function to their `Tick` delegate.

```
myTimer1.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
myTimer2.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor); //THE SAME LIKE FIRST ONE

private static void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject,
                                            EventArgs myEventArgs) {
}
```